# CURL return blank data but fine on Postman

Tags: php, curl

```
<?
include_once("simple_html_dom.php");

$cookie = "";
$ch = curl_init ();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"https://ebr1m.hasil.gov.my/SemakanKeluar.aspx?i=%2b2n0eU1wWL95mKKlIgQE%2bifqhY%2bMr3Vm%2b7cRxZnZsyI%3d");

echo $_GET['id'];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE,$cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$doc = str_get_html($data);
echo $doc;

?>
```

I tried on Postman, it's fine. But when I use curl (with same request data) it just doesn't return anything.

Comment: what is the output of `var_dump($data)`?

Comment: I run your code and got `$data` have value. so i think  `str_get_html($data)` is not working

Comment: @Anant +2n0eU1wWL95mKKlIgQE+ifqhY+Mr3Vm+7cRxZnZsyI=string(298) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK Cache-Control: private Content-Type: text/html Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0 Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=ucgdklqvzafrxwoxnulcdvvi; path=/; HttpOnly X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 X-UA-Compatible: IE=8,chrome=1 X-Host: 22 Date: Mon, 27 Jun 2016 12:37:12 GMT Content-Length: 0 "

Comment: what is that? i didn't get you?

Comment: @Anant http://i.imgur.com/nkYl01H.png

Comment: do you mind I send you my whole php file?

Comment: @Anant any idea why it doesn't work on my side?

Answer (score 0):

I use your code and everything is OK.

You tried

```
var_dump( $data );
var_dump( $doc );
```